# Subclassed MaterialView not showing MaterialDepth

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, calayer, cosmicmind

I have subclassed `MaterialView` and override `drawRect` to make a custom view which I then add as my tableViewFooter. As the title says I cannot get the depth to work. I've messed around with `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds` on varying layers/views without success. It is a tableView inside of a UIViewController just for clarity of my code.

```
    let receiptEdge = ReceiptEdge(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.w, height: 30))
    receiptEdge.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    receiptEdge.depth = MaterialDepth.Depth5

    //What I've tried messing with for an hour
    receiptEdge.clipsToBounds = false
    receiptEdge.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.tableView.clipsToBounds = false
    self.view.clipsToBounds = false
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = receiptEdge
```

My code for subclass `ReceiptEdge`

```
    override func prepareView() {
    super.prepareView()

    let rect = self.frame
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let receiptEdgeSize = CGFloat(rect.width / 75)
    var x = CGFloat(-receiptEdgeSize / 2)
    let y = rect.size.height / 2
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

    while x < rect.width {
        x += receiptEdgeSize
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        x += receiptEdgeSize
        path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), radius: receiptEdgeSize, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(0), clockwise: true)
        x += receiptEdgeSize
    }

    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: CGFloat(0)))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = path.CGPath

    self.layer.mask = layer
    self.visualLayer.mask = layer
    self.visualLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
}
```

Screenshot showing no depth

[image: No depth being shown]

Thanks in advance for someone that knows about layers more than I!
Here is a an example of a view where I have gotten depth to work on a subclass of `MaterialTableViewCell` using `MaterialDepth.Depth2`

[image]

Here is with `layer` having same path of `visualLayer`
[image]

Here I set no layer or path to `self.layer`. There is shadow but view or shadow not clipping to visual layer. set shadowColor to red so you could see the difference.

[image]

Comment: For those wondering what class `MaterialLayer` is I'm using [this](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) framework and have gotten depth to work on various views throughout my project.

Answer (score 0):

So the way depth works.

MaterialView is a composite object, which uses two layers to achieve its ability to clip the bounds and still offer a shadowing. A CAShapLayer called `visualLayer` is added as a sublayer to the backing layer of a view. So when an image is added, it is actually added to the visualLayer, which has the `masksToBounds` property set to true, and the layer property has its masksToBounds property set to false. This allows the depth property to be displayed on the `layer` property and still give the perception of a clipping.

In this line

```
receiptEdge.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

You are actually clipping the depth. So what I would try and do, is set this

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = layer
```

to the visualLayer property.

That should help you out, if not get you on the right path.

Comment: I do that at the end of my `override drawRect:` function after I draw the path. Should I not use it there? I think I've tried setting masks to bounds to false. I don't have access to that repo on my personal pc so I'll tinker with it tomorrow and get back to you. i guess I can try drawing and applying the layer after instantiating instead of in drawRect:

Comment: I wouldn't use drawRect in general. It is an expensive function to override and gives weird results if not used correctly. I would draw the path in the subclass using `prepareView` which is a method available in MaterialView to do those sort of things as a subclass.

Comment: now I have my `visualLayer` showing the bounds but my `layer` is still covering the whole rect. I know this because the shadow extends past my drawn path. If i set `self.layer.mask = layer` it takes the same shape but the view doesn't clip to bounds and no shadow is drawn. I'll put some screenshots in my answer to show you what i mean

Comment: Fyi i now deleted all `clipsToBounds` `masksToBounds` code so that it wouldn't interfere with default implementation of `layer` and `visualLayer`

Comment: I updated my code in the question to show what is currently in my code.

Comment: Cool I am taking a look.